# How to remove .php extension on Azure PHP Web App

Tags: azure, azure-webapps

How do I remove the .php extension on a Azure PHP Web App ?

using at htaccess file with the following, does NOT work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Ideas ?

Comment: What type of Azure WebApp did you deploy to? for Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Web Apps use IIS to host your application. The best equivalent of Apache's .htaccess system is actually using web.config file to handle URL rewrite in IIS.

For example, you can just put the following web.config file into your web app's root folder to hide .php extension.

**Referece:**

https://www.saotn.org/iis-url-rewrite-hide-php-extension.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="hide .php extension" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That was it, thanks alot Mohit Verma, perfect - good man, i knoew it was the web.config, but could not find the correct xml breakdown.